# Pause execution until any button pressed in swift

Tags: swift2, execution, pause

How can i pause execution until any button pressed in Swift 2?

--pause execution

if abuttonpressed == true {
x = x +10

--continue execution }

else {

--continue execution }

Comment: Would you be able to provide some details? You want to know how to get info if button was pressed?

Comment: No actually, i'm trying to pause all code and execution and continue execution after a specific button pressed

Comment: Well, maybe you could set a timer that would execute your code every x seconds and stop it after button tap? Then you could fire timer again after tapping button next time.

Comment: Why timer? Is there any syntax like pause() and continue() or something like that for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these are the things you are looking for. You could fire and invalidate timer at button taps.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "funcToRun", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire()
    timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: I know my English not so well :) Is there any code for pause execution and resume?

Comment: You can call timer.fire() in order to start executing the function in loops. If you want to stop it (not pause) you can call timer.invalidate(). I hope this will solve your problem.